# Same glyphe for multiple character

Tags: fontforge

I'm creating a mono glyph font (a font where all character are linked to the same glyph).

I've tried to unlink all characters references, draw the glyph into the ".notdef" character like the fontforge [documentation](http://fontforge.github.io/en-US/faq/) :

> **How do I set the default glyph of a font?**
>   If the glyph named “.notdef” contains some splines (but no references) then it will be used as the default glyph (that is the glyph used when an unencoded glyph is called for).

But it didn't work. When I test the font into a simple webpage, instead showing my default (.notdef) glyph for any character, it shows the character in the browsers default font.

**Test page**

```html
<hmtl>
    <head>
        <style>
            @font-face{
                font-family: test;
                src: url("test2.woff");
            }

            body div{
                font-family: test;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>0123456789azertyuiopqsdfghjklmwxcvbnAZERTYUIOPQSDFGHJKLMWXCVBN☼þ░┘</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Result** 
0123456789azertyuiopqsdfghjklmwxcvbnAZERTYUIOPQSDFGHJKLMWXCVBNâ˜¼Ã¾â–‘â”˜

instead of showing my glyph for all characters

Any ideas ?

Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work.  Did it not do anything? Did it do something you didn't want? Did it give you an error?

Comment: First things first, do you know what it means by an 'unencoded' glyph? I believe it means stuff like Alt+9999, that aren't contained in most fonts. Normally you'd just see a square: ☼ although here it's a little sun apparently

Comment: @MatthewD when i test the font into a simple webpage, instead showing my default (.notdef) glyph for any character, it show me the character of the browser default font

Comment: @CallumBradbury i think 'unencoded' glyph is simply there is no associate glyph for the character

Comment: You can think that, but that doesn't make it correct. If you don't associate a glyph with a character you get the default font, try doing an alt+ character like alt + 9999 and you'll see your custom glyph, I guarantee it.

Comment: nothing different... :(

Comment: @Yoplaboom did you find a solution? I'm trying to do the same thing